# TAPI on Windows Mobile 6.5: Incoming Calls distracted by default OS dialer

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, tapi, opennetcf

I'm building a app that could allow user to make calls and receive incoming calls. The application is build using `OpenNETCF` `TAPI` API.

There is no issue for making calls so far. But during incoming call, the OS own dialer will pop up when there's an incoming call, and when i code it to automatically answer all incoming calls, the OS own answering dialog will be shown instead of my application.

Is there a way where we can 'hijack' this? As in let my application to handle all event relating to receiving calls and making calls once it is fired up?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may simply replace cprog.exe by a dummy one that does nothing.

Comment: Any other way beside that? i can touch anything on the device...anything that i can do from my code to enable this?

Comment: sorry i mean i can't touch anything on the device OS level..

Comment: Starte here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379912/Make-Call-Blocker-Application-on-Windows-mobile